# Inherit JSDoc from generic parameter in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics, jsdoc

I have written a wrapper function `memoize` that caches the results of a function by its arguments. I would like the type hint for the wrapped function to show the original docs.

Here is what the type hint currently shows:

[image: Current type hint]

And here is how I have declared my `Memoized` type:

```
/**
 * Functions that match this type can be memoized.
 */
type Memoizable = (...args: any[]) => any;

/**
 * The memoized function.
 */
interface Memoized<T extends Memoizable> {
    /**
     * Memoized function that caches its results by a key built from its arguments.
     */
    (...args: Parameters<T>): ReturnType<T>;
    /**
     * The cache from which memoized items are retrieved.
     */
    readonly cache: Map<string, ReturnType<T>>;
}
```

So instead if the documentation for `Memoized`, I want to show the documentation for my function `test`. My guess is that I need to declare `Memoized` differently. What am I missing?

[View the full example on TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhCgAIUgVALAppAJogZgQwK4BsAukAtpgB4CWR2RkAzuQF7ID26k%20SkAxpl0gHRQQwcF2YA7WoTRY8%20AMK8kAGUrlCAXkgBGAAz6A3OHCgI0OJxk4C3JcgDWiAJ6QATolrNcAN0SvB5gBKiPjYrpLsnOjkrlKQmK4A5tSI4oSYtJHIPHwOzgEwCMjRselJKWl08Mx4KFnu6MzukABGyJh0%20K7k4okFQpAAAgAOCZg0CYmZHO3lRKn4meiuzDQA7vDkfOzM7JiOWZCOTgUiYpLSGNb4wZ4%20fgBckACyiETMt16%20rgA8ABRQSBAya6J5Sbq9AA0gKB-Dhk1oT0w4icAG0ALrgACUkA0AD54iiCVo-nD%20Aicfj4klaKjdOijCYwAMAGLYcRcfDkCSRTCEFrYci4FCZDo5TjHSDLVaQdSiuYLWincD4JzDZCvd6fe6-WCQRCkfCpEUvN7MRiYFq4RDEyAAoGw%20E0p4ABTG8yNsR%20sDx2NxBPBPUSjNMrPZnO5EQ4fOIfO2HHI0zV2WRrWQ83ejEQKGVqvVpszDEt1txdrJCKRKIxlIJyKcIeZ5iKxDNWbq6HDXIkyp6nqwXA1raYKG9%20sNxsymvNRatNsgAG8YZBQw6gTAp22pZ3I7zCOKPLLFm4PHJMi0XB1JQKhYRpTQ5dTkvM0kql9ARKvSU6pq73SE-LQ3p4liTzBKE4SwMmQFGKuK6roUnD7lKKzrJs2wZtO2aHm88rIO4XTkIgvg5m%20whLu4mAoBIuAuPuTzPJgww-IGUKQGBYTiJB6pAXiRgAL7GCuMAAPLDF24iYLgdAhFyvRLE0hwYVmW4cuJPZpH4-aDoWiCieJgF6gaRriCaG4ztaBKLrBjbwRY6ZkJA4jUG0riQKw2FEJkPSHPuAS2QA6kg4iHPQTBuWwMy2LkY4Dtm0ybJkuBqPgkKHNaGSEO4A5pDRkDYLQWHqDh1J4WaxHITKkW%20aRkAACJXKeOyQAABlYciKLkqhEOozV%20Q6ZGrhRVHiLl%205deoAD8TxOUQLkwQ6cH9ZAbKqTu0aZSEHHxSm0XHH1a51Q1BDTLsrVHTcHhfH4vWkR%20DpDdRLjuHc3xTQWHyXTq0HgAJTJmDAHVINtx60I17mRYk5C%20MFHarTy57xEczitIKNh3oe8pPoq-TmIFqSHLDEY8omti4NadSYIkmDeY0rmRbQ4yzFjL6pZFz1yLKmT4RxWHo1VdiyhciCUTjMAAKoFS1SlMM1kAbKkRF%20JATg1I5iBYfguzuOqMapga6qSFD2SrMM2D4HyO6sMZouQAAkmwKthCpRPBebjiZFQBDkMMJaTBUiypQp5ARVEMRxH7z6EO5juuYT4mc45zDpJ0EKJKljtVDUwqQKMtCitw%20WazQzXPVdrg3dAAx4%20Iit05woUsCHO2cAasUmhDRvBc1Y3Jc1rOcOlcRZQsuX5VhCzdAeJPuO85V84hdgFJAACaqs8MFzBiZGkm5T0XAUZLCloPvwuS-TyngwvuQ2yM7rO3Zzvx%205GxbPAhzs8dme1GmUVICR5i31cOMNyW8JCZHkBIaIyQgHx1GEAj0AFlRxx3NLRAo4jITnehaWceJ7QOkJk8WA0JVxWVXA6Hu3VNCoHOoDRA40Upvnup9b4pY2oEG1N8JcfF6JDl0qAyQQFSzzgEiBLBw5BGkKBOcOISEtA1zWC8RizECKsXYhBKCPpcFYkZKuZBPJUEoC-OSZ0kA3TwP-F6H0OJJFkOkYQSUWhS46nJMMH2Tg-hOTJqlCkOiyFAmDnaXy8AMh-GOFiHE3Nwi-0QPwRIIRQnOG0cYPx-i2B-F8g3SAeItAUPUDiXyXB0quD%20EkxhUiwGEG8JJbAyAtCExcW4jxeBcDeJpKUlJ0T%20AFXwAkpwqUqm4Bqe0lJkTgoDJqfNIEv1Vx2JBhzLQwkWgACtECcn4DIHoiAXQrHVK4VUfwDGpQAOT7iOalGxq44n4CeCU-00SuHDKBKMuZBB%20KCUbAhEmJMOgoGoEQFwejxADAGIA4BHQADKqxkBwMZp6IQIhAXsA8D0zAYIVGJGseRTaUTMA-WMLMgxpZUF-CNFILExgKXgAMX8I5mAjlYiAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the solution was to declare `Memoized` as follows:

```
/**
 * Memoized function that exposes its cache.
 */
type Memoized<T extends Memoizable> = T & Memo<T>

/**
 * A memoized function exposes its cache as a read-only attribute.
 */
interface Memo<T extends Memoizable> {
    /**
     * The cache from which memoized items are retrieved.
     */
    readonly cache: Map<string, ReturnType<T>>;
}
```

Now the type hint looks like this:

[image: Correct type hint]

[View the full example on TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhCgAIUgVALAppAJogZgQwK4BsAukAtpgB4CWR2RkAzuQF7ID26k%20SkAxpl0gHRQQwcF2YA7WoTRY8%20AMK8kAGUrlCAXkgBGAAz6A3OHCgI0OJxk4C3JcgDWiAJ6QATolrNcAN0SvB5gBKiPjYrpLsnOjkrlKQmK4A5tSI4oSYtJHIPHwOzgEwCMjRselJKWl08Mx4KFnu6MzukABGyJh0%20K7k4okFQpAAAgAOCZg0CYmZHO3lRKn4meiuzDQA7vDkfOzM7JiOWZCOTgUiYpLSGNb4wZ4%20fgBckACyiETMt16%20rgA8ABRQSBAya6J5Sbq9AA0gKB-Dhk1oT0w4icAG0ALrgACUkA0AD54iiCVo-nD%20Aicfj4klaKjdOijCYwAMAGLYcRcfDkCSRTCEFrYci4FCZDo5TjHSDLVaQdSiuYLWincD4JzDZCvd6fe6-WCQRCkfCpEUvN7MRiYFq4RDEyAAoGw%20E0p4ABTG8yNsR%20sDx2NxBPBPUSjNMrPZnO5EQ4fOIfO2HHI0zV2WRrWQ83ejEQKGVqvVpszDEt1txdrJCKRKIxlIJyKcIeZ5k15qYdXQ4a5POjhANw2YtA8ssWtlyueTBZb2e9%20sNxsyzYtVptpb1ADIJ97fUyzDAAILEM1ZtsdyMzvsDzJykecDLxNyITAoAC0ElwLj5XXIAqNyp6nqwXAama04Gka4gmguRZLgSADeMKQKGDpAoUnDisUKzrJs2wZpOdTqG88rIO4n6IL4ObwdAIhIe4j6vi4aFPM8mDDD8gZQpAwShOEsDJpueJGAAvsYiEwAA8sMnbiJguB0CEXK9EsTSHDhWZSieEi-mkfgAUBhaIOJkm0CBs7gfOh5QdasHwYhSEoemZCQOI1BtK4kCsEOBGyuIhxoQEtmQAA6kg3kzHQqnuaFaEzoB2bTJsmS4Go%20CQoc1oZIQ7iAWkb6QNgA54UaRCEfe7xkVKGE%20XYfkOjAAAiVxyNMuwAAZWHIii5KoRDqM11XIVRDo0SgdHXogXXqAA-E8TlEC5RhITZNWQGyHKSbyGUhGEUaoXYRz5BRdUNQQTWQK1R03B4Xx%20L1B0DUCQ0je4dzfFNE7at8m6CcJjYwB1SBxURHiNW5bChYk5C%20N57araeLTvntLgCkKhDSjQV6TBUiz9OYQWpIc0MRjyia2Lg1p1JgiSYD0UpKaFtDjLMyTzGktApaFT1yLKmTEVt2blTKkW7T0UgPuR0ADAAqgOp0qUwzWQBsqSkX4kBODUjmIHz%20C7O46oxqmvapPQvjcKswzYPgfKnqwYHYzAACSbBq2Eakw12%20yDlQBDkMMJYY8ziwpUp5Cg1EMRxP7Cwg6rNSuQTa3E%20IzDpJ0EKJClztVDUwqQKMtCitweXazQzVPVdrg3eLOPBcrrl0%20Focprk0WayaYMQ3jzVoeN%20DNWznBpXEmULDleV8ws3SDsT7ilXzqOVaOAwAJrqzw3nMBJkbSTlPRcDR0tKWge8PtL9dMNHguL1XMAjO6rtcBYxTqevbAbFs8CHBzx1Z7UaajWLN9RiuHGG5TeEhMjyAkNEZIwC1pAIZp6JUQgRDx1PLLRAxkwIQXMsWG09oHQEyeLAaESE4JISQt3JKpY2oED%20mNJKJDyH3Uujqah513p%20HggJRi5l9JgMkJuUsMEhJYh4XpFAgiyEOnOHEKKWhxCIDWC8ZirFPzsU4ltHi6o%20J-CxIyJCqCeToJQKSJ0UxXTuhCH4IyPocRSKYTIwgkotBlx1OSYYvsnB-CcqTFKFJ9FMNlGwP4vl4AZD%20McLEOIebhFGvwRIIQInOD0cYQJQS7S%20XoOfPEWhKHdXwDiXyXA0quF0QEhx4DCDeGktgZAWgCbuM8d4vAuA-E0hSRRaRVUBz4CSU4FK1TcC1I6WkmJ3lBm1Pmg6IS8FHH3loJzLQokWgACtECcn4DIHoiAXQrHVK4VUfxjEpQAORoROSlex5CEn4CeLo-0o0uEjMGptWJX98BfW3AMBAxNiYdBQNQIgLhDHiAGAMW%20wCJiQAAMqrGQPAj0nDKLgBBewDwvTMBgjUYkOx8ExnxHADMuZxjSzoL%20EaKQWJjDUvAMYv4JzMAnKpUAA)